# postcss import iconfont .woff .ttf not found

Tags: css, filepath, postcss

I imported iconfont.css by npm css package, but the iconfont.woff and the iconfont.tff not found. How can I solve it?

#### gulpfile

```
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var atImport = require('postcss-import');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');

gulp.task('importcss', function () {
    var processors = [
        atImport({}),
        cssnano()
    ];
    return gulp.src('./htdocs/css/common.css')
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./htdocs/css-build/'))
});
```

#### Npm Css Fonticont

[image]

#### css/common.css

[image]

#### css-build/common.css

[image]

#### page

[image]

Comment: how are you importing the icon fonts? i see nothing, which makes me think you inline them...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url after postcss-import. postcss-url will adjust your URL paths.

By default, it will adjust your URLs to reference the original files in `node_modules`.

If you do not include `node_modules` in your deployments, it will not work. To fix that, set the [`url` option](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-url#url) to `copy`. This will copy all the assets to `css-build/assets/` and adjust the URLs accordingly.

You can also set `url` to `inline`, which will base64 encode all your assets and inline them. I don't recommend using this unless your assets are very small.